# Is it possible to pass a jQuery object as a constructor parameter to a typescript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, constructor, reference

We are trying to figure out a peculiar behaviour of typescript. In the following two code examples, a jQuery object should be altered by typescript. In the example that works fine, we reference the jQuery object by using the selector engine in a method after our typescript class is instantiated. This works:

```
namespace Company.Module {
    export class GenericService {
        private statefulObject: JQuery;

        public constructor( ) {
        }

        private _toggleObjectState(): void {
            this._statefulObject.toggleClass('text-hide text-success');
        }

        public SetObjectState(): void {
            this.statefulObject = $('#statefulObject');
            _toggleObjectState();
        }

    }
}
```

Whereas passing the jQuery object in the constructor does not work:

```
namespace Company.Module {
    export class GenericService {
        private statefulObject: JQuery;

        public constructor( _statefulObject: JQuery ) {
            this.statefulObject = _statefulObject;
        }

        private _toggleObjectState(): void {
            this._statefulObject.toggleClass('text-hide text-success');
        }

        public SetObjectState(): void {
            _toggleObjectState();
        }

    }
}
```

We would like to understand why this is the case.

Comment: Your first example doesn't compile.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author wants to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this was a non-issue. Our code did not work because we were referencing an object that was added to the DOM dynamically. When passed to the `typescript` constructor, the object simply was not loaded in the DOM, therefore it could not be manipulated. *Moderators please feel free to remove this question.*